# How can I get each element of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This array comes from a database. 
 `print_r($row['index']);` outputs `Array ( [index] => ["228","227","219","229","60"] )`  
My goal is to handle each element of the array separately, using a for loop. So I would like to have something like:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($row['index']); $x++) { 
   $ind = $row['index'][$x]; // first element is 228, then 227, ... 
}
```

I get the following on applying json_encode on it

```
{"to_read_later":"[\"228\",\"227\",\"219\",\"229\",\"60\"]"}
```

and become this error:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`
> How could I handle it?

Comment: Why are you applying JSON when it is already an array you can loop through? `foreach($row['index'] AS $index) {echo $index;}` should be all you need.

Comment: @JayBlanchard , It outputs `$index = ["228","227","219","229","60"]`.  And the first element is `[`. So it behaves like a string, and not an array. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What outputs that? You should not have to apply JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print_r() indicates that the $row array has the following structure:

```
$row = [
    'index' => [
        'index' => '["228","227","219","229","60"]'
    ]
];
```

So `json_decode($row['index'], 1)` will return an error because `$row['index']` is an array.

Instead you need to apply `json_decode($row['index']['index'], 1)` to decode the json string.

```
$inds = json_decode($row['index']['index'], 1);

print_r($inds);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 228
    [1] => 227
    [2] => 219
    [3] => 229
    [4] => 60
)
```

Comment: You don't have to apply JSON methods at all. [You can just loop through the array](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11cf77d93f2bb2c0fd864ed967edccdef28f8079) because it is just an array and not JSON to begin with.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think it may actually be JSON stored in this array, otherwise the print_r() would have output `Array ( [index] => Array ( [0] => 228 [1] => 227 [2] => 219 [3] => 229 [4] => 60 ) )`

Comment: Not necessarily, see my example. It is an array containing another array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON in your output, so there is no need to apply `json_decode()`. You can simply loop through your array like this:

```
$row['index'] = array("index"=>["228","227","219","229","60"]);
foreach($row['index']['index'] as $index) {
    echo $index ."\n";
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11cf77d93f2bb2c0fd864ed967edccdef28f8079)